# File corruption in append mode

Tags: file, append, fopen

Main question is: can data be corrupted by appending new data to the end of the file (bearing in mind hard disk sector size for example of 512)?

What if for example i have file with 1023 bytes, append 1 byte, and i have crush (power loss, disk buffer issues etc...)?

In what condition will be the second sector in this scenario?

Comment: It depends on your filesystem. For instance a journaling filesystem will be more likely to bring back your data.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say. There's multiple layers of abstraction, cacheing, and even simple electrical propagation delays to account for.

Your code may have written out a byte. But the OS is not going to immediately write out that byte. Hitting a drive is one of the absolute slowest operations that a computer can do these days, so it's going to buffer that byte and see if any further bytes getting stuck into the output buffer.

If nothing occurs within the cache's timeout period, then the bytes will be sent to the drive to be committed to media. But the drive itself may also do some cacheing, etc... There's rotational delay to account for (the actual sector the byte should go into has to actually be under the write head to be written, which can be several milliseconds).

In other words, writing a byte out to disk can take essentially a random amount of time to actually be written out onto the disk media. If the power failure hits during this interval, your data is lost.

Comment: I think question is in fact, in what condition will be whole sector if hard disk writes data PER sector. what will be with 511 bytes of second sector?

Comment: Again, depends on just how far the write operation got before the power loss hit. If the byte's written to disk, but the system metadata (file size) isn't updated, then the OS will still see the file at 1023 bytes after the machine boots again. Even a journaling file system will not protect against power loss - because you're still writing data to a file on the disk as the power goes away. journals make writes a bit quicker because the metadata+data are written at the same time, but can't do ANYTHING about the power vanishing half-way through (or before) the write operation.

Comment: But what if we skip software layer of OS, what will be with data BEFORE write has been occurred? Can i lost some data that already is on disk plate? As i understand, if minimal disk io block is sector block, then I'm assuming that write begins at 513 byte starting from beginning of second sector size. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, the drive'll have to read the entire sector, put in the modified data, then write out the whole sector. it doesn't do byte-level IO. Once the modified bytes are on the physical disk, they can't be lost. but if the associated metadata is updated as well, then they're effectively lost because the record of their presence is not there.

Comment: only if it's on disk, and the metadata that SAYS it's on disk are there, then yes. it's "safe". But it's like trying to get through a big door that's closing. you're either entirely through, or you get trapped or cut in half. it's an all-or-nothing situation.